# Create ingress controller in namespace Kubernetes

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am learning a bit about ingress. It consists of 2 parts:

- Ingress resource: *"How do you want to route requests to the backing services?"*
- Ingress controller: *"Listens to Kubernetes API for Ingress resources."*

I've deployed an ingress controller in namespace called ingress. I've also deployed a default backend. Now I want to deploy an application (svc, deployment of pods etc).

Do I need to deploy this application also in the namespace `ingress`? It seems logical to me I have to deploy a new ingress resource for every new application, but how is this working for the Ingress controller?

Do I have to create one ingress controller for every namespace or is it recommended to use on ingress controller over multiple namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ingress resource must be in the same namespace as the backend service. This can be any namespace doesn't need to be the same as the controller

Comment: So I can deploy my controller in a namespace called nginx, and my app + ingress resource + ingress backend in a different namespace?

Comment: Correct, controller can go in one namespace, deployment service and ingress in another

Comment: When I check the yaml to deploy a controller I see it expects default-backend-service in its namespace. So there must be a default backend service in the namespace of my controller and a resource can be in a different namespace with a different default-backend?

Comment: Or will it just keep on restarting till it can find a default backend service somewhere?

Comment: I'm referring to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml line:             - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend

Comment: When the controller can't find a backend configured to serve the request it is sent to the default backend. The one included in most ingress walkthroughs always returns 404 but you can do your own thing. It is deployed in the same namespace as the controller because it makes sense conceptually, I don't know if you could deploy it in a different namespace

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand :)